# Can I safely remove this sill?

Tags: floor, leveling

We are putting in a new terrace and we have these sills or transitions on the outside of the doors which hang over the terrace. See picture below.

My preference would be to remove these sills and raise the terrace somewhat so the floor inside and outside are more levelled. But I can't assess if I can safely remove the sills without later having problems with e.g. moisture or frost.

The question is can I remove these sills safely?

[image]

Comment: That is a nicely tiled sill and I would think twice about modifying it, but I have never seen a sloping sill and wonder how one would traverse it. Is a sloping sill commonplace in the Netherlands? My initial thought is it would be treacherous. What about placing a ramp that continues the slope of the sill down to the patio? Would this be a dangerously steep ramp? What about a ramp at a more gradual slope starting either at the door (covering the sill) or starting at the bottom edge of the sill? Do you want to roll carts out this door. Want safety for mobility impaired?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you couldn't go with the plan you are thinking of. It's probably concrete under it so it'll take a bit of work to get it off. You could consider using an angle grinder with a diamond blade and cut a groove across the front of the door to ensure any pieces that do break off don't break off under the door. probably will have to do this a few times until you get to the level you want.

Comment: I would agree it appears to be concrete, remember if you have floor joists inside they are sitting under there also. As long as this area is covered the new level could be almost even (I always like a small slope away from an opening).

Comment: You do not state whether the area is protected from the weather. Is the surface further out (to the right) level or draining away from the door? You might need that sill to protect from rainwater glowing into the house if you level it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the picture I would not remove this sloping sill. It looks like the bottom of the masonary in the adjacent wall is at the level of the sill at the outside. You want the level of the patio to be several inches below the bottom of the masonary.

I do not think it wise to raise the impervious level of the patio. You will get drainage back into the wall.

Is the current arrangement a tripping hazard?